# Downloading the response from an api call as a csv onClick

Tags: javascript, api, csv, download, window

I am attempting create a button for downloading a csv file when an item is selected from a dropDown list. Ive done this before but the response returned this time is different than what im use to. I could use some help understanding how to format things to correctly download and display the data in a csv file when the api is hit.

so far I have an onClick function that looks like this:

```
const onDownloadReport = (type) => {
    const org = type === "All" ? "" : type;
    api.providerPayroll
      .reports({
        date: activePayPeriod,
        org: org,
      })
      .then((res) => {
         window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + res);
      });
  };
```

this works to download the csv file. However it doesnt contain the actual data in the response it shows null in the csv. When i try to console out the `res` I get null as well. Im not sure what Im missing here for capturing the response.

And the code for the endpoint `reports()`

```
reports: (payload) => requests.post("/reporting/download-payroll-report", payload),
```

Reports follows the same patter as all other api calls in the project.

If I need to add more information on this please let me know.

Comment: What does `res` result in? And I assume `escape` is the deprecated window global?

Comment: `res` is `null` so thats whats showing in the csv thats downloaded. The part I cant figure out is how to use what is actually returned from the api. The api is returning the info its just not captured in `res`. But good to know about `escape` I can take that out it works just the same without it.

Comment: If `res` is `null`, then there's a problem in your `api.providerPayroll.reports(...)`. That means it's resolving with `null`, and `"abc" + null === "abcnull"`.

Comment: Ok, it seems like the api call is successful, I say this because upon inspecting the network call Ive found it returns 200 with a full response not null.  This is really stumping me, the code itself in `api.providerPayroll.reports(...)` is pretty simple but Ive updated my question to reflect what it looks like right now.

Comment: Make sure **that `res` itself** is not `null`, perhaps `reports` doesn't properly return the HTML request's result.

Comment: check the `reports()`s documentation, may be it returns in a `(err, res)` way

Comment: @AzizaKasenova do you mean like add a `.catch` following my then? Or could you explain what you mean?

Comment: if `res` is null, then `reports`  definitely at the fault, you say that the network call contains full response, but `reports` is not returning the response in the promise. Can you show us the code for `reports()`?

Comment: you can try adding `.catch()`, but what I mean is, we need the `.reports()` interface/docs to see what it returns and in what format

Comment: You're currently POSTing data to the `.reports()` endpoint to get data, can you check in the documentation/the code that this is how the API is configured ?